# How to have segmentedControl and UISearchController as UITableViewController header? (Programmatically)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have created a UISearchController: `let mySearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)` and a segmented control:

```
var mySegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
    let items = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: items)

    return segmentedControl
}
```

How would I have BOTH of these be my UITableViewController header? I tried putting them both into a UIView, and making the UIView the header, but the search bar was not functional when doing it this way.

How should this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `scopeButtonTitles` property:

```
mySearchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
```

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823516/how-to-add-scope-buttons-in-a-uisearchcontroller-embedded-in-uinavigationcontrol/39493600#39493600) for more details.

UPDATE: Added response to scopeButton changes:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) { 
    // respond to your scopeBar selection here
    switch selectedScope {
    case 0:
        print("tab One selected")
        tableView.tintColor = UIColor.red
    case 1:
        print("tab two selected")
        tableView.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    case 2:
        print("tab Three selected")
        tableView.tintColor = UIColor.yellow
    default:
        print("Someone added a tab!")
}
```

Comment: If I use these, will I be able to modify the color of the TableViewController depending on which scope is selected?

Comment: I don't see why not. Try using `func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) { // respond to your scopeBar selection here }`

Comment: Here's a link to the docs:https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchbardelegate/1624280-searchbar You have to implement the `UISearchBarDelegate`

Comment: not sure if you meant `tintColor` or something else but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

You can add scope button using searchBar's scope bar property.

```
[yourSearchBar setShowsScopeBar:YES]; 
[yourSearchBar setScopeButtonTitles:@[@"button1",@"button2"]];
```

**By storyboard**
[image]

Comment: Doing it programmatically, updated the post to reflect this. Do you know how to do it programmatically or only in storyboards?